# Laravel migrations issue - remove the word 'public' in url

Tags: laravel, server, routes

I moved my laravel instance to a new server.
I have updated the env file and the database connection file and the instance is working with the small exception of the url.

When I type the url:  https://domain-name.com

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache Server at domain_name.com Port 443"

When I type:  https://domain-name.com/public   (I have to use the domain/public convention on all routes)

It all works fine.  I have searched the forums etc and there are a few proposed solutions, none of which seem to work (The solutions range form updating the .htaccess file, to registing the url in the bootstrap/app.php files) none of which are making a difference.

Has anyone experienced this issue and can recommend a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced this one, but I don't know if this will work for you.

1) Navigate to **bootstrap** folder and delete all the contents inside the **cache** folder.

2) Create an .htaccess file to your project's directory. If .htaccess file is already present, proceed to Step 3. You don't need a duplicate one.

3) In the .htaccess file, copy and paste this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

4) Navigate to public folder (not the public_html folder). Public folder is present inside your Laravel's project. Create an .htaccess file and paste this code. Again, if .htaccess file is already present, just edit that file and copy the code below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

5.) That's it. Hopefully, this one will for you. Cross fingers

Comment: Great Start! very detailed answer.

Comment: Perfect - worked like a charm and well explained - you sir have my thanks.